# XAMPP: There is no application set to open the document on Mac Ventura

Tags: xampp, macos-ventura

I have installed XAMPP 8.0.28-0 om Mac OS Ventura. I do not have this issue on Mac OS Monterey.

I am unable to launch XAMPP from the Applications folder using manager-osx launcher, I get the error below and I cannot find a suitable application to use to open it when I click on the "Choose Application" button in the popup.

### The error is:

### There is no application set to open the document “manager-osx”.

However I am able to launch XAMPP immediately after installing it when I leave the checkbox checked in the installer. Please assist and advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figure out a solution.

It appears that the shortcut for manager-osx had an issue.

So I was able to open XAMPP directly from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/manager-osx. I then proceeded to right click the file and create an Alias and moved the alias to the XAMPP folder. Problem solved!